# Long UL list in DIV, auto scroll to LI element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have such a weird problem, I have a div

```
_inputHelper // it has fixed height ( 200px )
```

with very,very long `<ul>` list in it ( around 200 of elements) and I would like to scroll using jQuery to some `<li>` on the list, but the problem is that, when I scroll whole list in such a way:

```
$( _inputHelper.find('ul') ).animate( { top : -1 * ( $(_this).position().top - $(_this).height() ) } , 200);
```

> ```
> _this is a LI element I would like to scroll to
> ```

is scrolled down in good place, but I cannot scroll list using mouse, here is a printscreen to be more precise:

[image: long UL in div auto scroll problem]

I think I may scroll in wrong way, but I've tried also scrollTop/margin-top and it still didn't work.

some tests: http://jsfiddle.net/uk5xqfry/3/

Any help?

Comment: use `scrollTop` instead of `top` ... can you share the markup or make an example on jsfiddle

Comment: ups, sorry misspelling, I've mean scrollTop, not scrollTo :) I will try to do some jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uk5xqfry/3/ here you go :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your Fiddle you need to use `scrollTop`, try this:

```
$('.input-helper').animate({
    scrollTop : $("#test").position().top,
}, 200);
```

Check the **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk5xqfry/5/)**

---

In your code you are just moving the `ul` element and then is out of the parent view; now with this you are changing the scroll of the parent.

Comment: Ok, so I have to scroll div itself, not the ul list :) thanks, to much coding for today ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember having this issue once, a number of years back (scrolling an inner element to a certain point, versus scrolling the viewport to an element) and I think I resolved it with a jQuery plugin that I found.    Made it simple.

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo